# The top of the page is displayed for a fraction of second when trying to set focus to a <div> in $.ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have different categories on my Index.cshtml and on clicking of any of the categories, I am displaying the products of that category. The html  containing the product list is updated with a partial view on the success of $.ajax. The products are displayed according to the category selected, but for a fraction of a second the top part of the view is displayed before the updating of the `<div>`.

My Index page.

```
 <section id="portfolio" class="section-bg">
        <div class="container" id="focusdiv" tabindex="-1">
            <header class="section-header">
                <h3 class="section-title">Our Portfolio</h3>
            </header>
            <div id="listproducts" class="text-center">

                <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                    <li><a id="all" href="#">All </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="inserts" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="The optimum usage of the Insert has to be determined by having a controlled low flank wear to reuse the Insert.
                       Reworking can be done only on Inserts with minimum Flank Wear or regular Flank Wear.">
                            Inserts
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a id="cutters" href="#">Cutters</a></li>
                    <li><a id="angular" href="#">Angular Heads</a></li>
                    <li><a id="special" href="#">Specialized-Customized</a></li>
                    <li><a id="dialholders" href="#">Dial Holders</a></li>


                </ul>
                <input id="currentcategory" type="hidden" value="all" />
            </div>
            
            <div id="displayproducts">
                
                @{Html.RenderAction("AllProducts" );}
               
            </div>

        </div>
    </section><!-- #portfolio -->
```

My partial view

```
@model Monotech.Models.ProductViewModel

@if (Model.Products != null)
{    
<div id="firstdiv" class="container">
    <div class="row">



        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
        {

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="#" class="img-prod">
                        @if (product.ImageUrl != null)
                        {
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="@Url.Content(product.ImageUrl)">
                        }
                    </a>


                    <div class="portfolio-info">
                        <h4>@product.Name</h4>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>

        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination">

                @if (Model.Pager != null && Model.Pager.TotalPages > 1)
                {

                    if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage > 1)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-pageNo="@Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1">Previous</a>
                        </li>

                    }

                    for (var page = Model.Pager.StartPage; page <= Model.Pager.EndPage; page++)
                    {
                        string activeClass = Model.Pager.CurrentPage == page ? "active bg-info" : string.Empty;

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-pageNo="@page">@page</a>
                        </li>

                    }

                    if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage < Model.Pager.TotalPages)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-pageNo="@Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1">Next</a>
                        </li>



                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    }
```

My $.ajax function():

```
$("#dialholders").click(function () {
        var category = 'dialholders';
        $("#currentcategory").val(category);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ToolsCategory",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                category: category
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#displayproducts").html(data);
               
                $("#focusdiv").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
               // $('body').scrollTo('#focusdiv'); 
            },
        });
    });
```

The action method of the Home controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ToolsCategory(string category, int? pageNo)
{
    ProductViewModel products = new ProductViewModel();
    ProductView productview = new ProductView();
    var pageSize = 10;
    int totalRecords;

    pageNo = pageNo.HasValue ? pageNo.Value > 0 ? pageNo.Value : 1 : 1;
    if (category == "all" || category == null)
    {
        totalRecords = productview.GetAllProductsCount();
        products.Products = productview.GetAllProducts(pageNo.Value, pageSize);
    }
    else
    {
        totalRecords = productview.GetProductsCategoryCount(category);
        products.Products = productview.GetProductsCategoryWise(category, pageNo.Value);
    }
    products.Categories = productview.GetCategories();
    products.Pager = new Pager(totalRecords, pageNo, pageSize);

    return PartialView("_Products", products);
}
```

Please help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: Not sure why you're *not* expecting this to happen.  You render your page, send it to the user, which displays the page then parses the js, then starts an ajax call - "sometime" later, the ajax call completes and updates the page.   This is also called FOUC - flash of unstyled content - generally when updating things like menus via js.   The solution is to load your data in the initial action and render it once - or add `display:none` to the content you don't want shown with a `.show()` when it's ready to show.

Comment: The data is dynamically changing based on the category selection, The result is as expected, it is just that before the partial page <div> is updated , the contents of the page flash for a sec.